# Highcharts, calling incorrect array from database

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

Calling MySQL data to PHP page.  I'm fairly new but to PHP and SQL.  I've determined (in JsFiddle) that the array is incorrect.

```
series: [{     data: [[{"date":"2013-02-16","distance":[4.16]},{"date":"2013-02-17","distance":[1.6]},{"date":"2013-02-19","distance":[1.2]},{"date":"2013-02-25","distance":[1.2]}]],
    pointStart: 0,
    pointInterval
                }]
```

I'm trying to call the running data from the last 7 days.  The call to the DB is...

```
<?          
$series=array();
$last30= mysql_query("SELECT `date`, `distance` FROM `training` WHERE date>= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)AND user_id = 1");
        while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($last30)) {
          $serie=array(
             "date" => $item['date'],
             "distance" => array(floatval($item['distance']))
          );
          array_push($series,$serie);
        }

        ?>
```

I feel like the PHP formatting of, date" => $item['date'], is what's causing the problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/wphZe/

Answer (score 0):

You should use json_encode() to encode your array in php and then load it in chart. Morever you need to parse your own data to timestamps (time in miliseconds).

I suggest to familiar with documentation about preprocessing data: http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing